# What happens when I answer my own question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, answers

If I answer my own question on Stack Overflow: will my points increase, decrease or stay the same? How is it working?

Comment: .... you don't get rep from answering. you get rep from votes. The same will happen whether it's your answer on your question or your answer elsewhere. People DO tend to downvote self-answered questions more though, so be careful

Comment: @Patrice More accurately, self-answered questions tend to merit downvotes more often because they're rather hard to write *well*.

Comment: @Patrice thanks, but how people will know that I answered my question if no one answered my question?

Comment: @MosabShaheen well... it's clearly written who writes what post... so anyone who bothers to check will see.

Comment: @Patrice I mean I didn't get any reply on my question that's why I answered mine later, not because I already have the answer and just posting it.

Comment: @MosabShaheen I see. Doesn't really change that the fact this is self-answered will still be clear from anyone who sees your Q & A. But yeah, Servy's point is also important. it's hard to write a good self-answered Q&A pair... but if it's a good Q&A, then you shouldn't worry about answering yourself.

Comment: @Patrice Thanks, so from your experience, if no one answered my question and later I get the answer is it better to not post it because I will get down vote ?

Comment: @MosabShaheen this is absolutely not what Patrice and Servy are saying - it is hard to write good question *when you know the answer*, but if the question stand on its own for some time (i.e. couple days) it is unlikely to get new downvotes for quality of the question if later you posted an answer.

Comment: I would say that you should make sure your question is useful and on topic before answering it since that bumps it back to the beginning of the list of active questions. For example, in the question you're asking about it isn't clear that it's a programming question. You also ask for anything that would help and explicitly mention plugins even though requests for off site resources are off topic.

Comment: The existing down vote is also a signal that the question needs improvement.

Comment: ["To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is *explicitly encouraged***." -Jeff Atwood (SO co-founder)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: On MSE: [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2706/178816)

Answer (score 15):

If no one votes on the question or answer, your points will remain the same.

If people vote up on the question or answer, your points will go up.

If people vote down on the question or answer, your points will go down.

---

You yourself are not allowed to vote on your posts, though you can accept your own answer (which doesn't give you points).

Comment: Thanks, If I answered someone's question and he/she marked my post as answer then I take points immediately or also I need the voting up from others.

Comment: Also If someone vote up my post even if it is not marked as answer, shall I take points?

Comment: Upvotes on your questions give you 5 points. Upvotes on your answers give you 10 points. Being accepted or not has nothing to do with it. I suggest you read about [how reputation works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work). That has all the details.

Comment: I followed the link you gave there is "one of your answers becomes accepted: +15"

Comment: @MosabShaheen And Oded *specifically* addressed that in the answer.

Comment: @Servy Oded said "Being accepted or not has nothing to do with it." but in the link "one of your answers becomes accepted: +15"

Comment: I did say in my answer: `though you can accept your own answer (which doesn't give you points)`

Comment: @MosabShaheen "And Oded specifically addressed that **in the answer**."  You're quoting a later comment.

Comment: But "though you can accept your own answer (which doesn't give you points)" is different from "Being accepted or not has nothing to do with it" which means someone else accepted you, Right?
Anyway let's focus on the information: if some one accepts your answer u take +15 and If you marked your post as answer you will not take points.

Comment: @MosabShaheen Yes, those two sentences are different. The first one answers the question that you asked, the second doesn't; it says something else.

Comment: @MosabShaheen "Being accepted or not has nothing to do with it" was in response to your first comment, where you asked if the +15 rep didn't happen until there are upvotes. Being accepted always gives +15 rep, regardless of any votes, and an upvote always gives +10 rep, regardless of being accepted by the person who asked the question.